# iTerm scrollback limit not working?

Tags: iterm

I have set the scrollback limit to 20000 for the Default Profile:

[image]

However the scrolling only has 1000 lines. I verified by tiny python program writing 1200 lines to an output file and then `cat`ing the file. only the first 960 were shown (I had some 40 lines of other stuff apparently).

What am I missing?

Comment: How many lines in your Terminal window?  If it’s not a multiple of 25, those, may be lines you are missing.

Comment: 1000 lines.  i don't really understand  your question maybe

Comment: A terminal screen is normally 25 lines, however this can be adjusted.

Comment: This question is about the scrollback not the terminal size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quitting `iTerm` completely and restarting fixed the issue.  I had mistakenly assumed that closing individual tabs/sessions and then creating new sessions would be sufficient.

Comment: Consider marking your answer as accepted if it answers your problem as you said. It avoids it being bumped by Community bot as unsolved.

Comment: @Thinkr  Yea i forgot about this: need to wait 2 days before accepting own answer

Comment: I know, it's annoying. :)